# "Required fields are missing" on non-null field

Tags: api, permissions, required-field

My organization uses a third-party relational replication tool to sync data between Salesforce and a SQL Server database. The replication software is written in Java and uses the Salesforce API for its CRUD operations. Each object, both standard and custom, is represented in the database as a table that, in addition to all object fields, contains additional fields that are used for replication purposes.

When trying to insert a record into Salesforce via MSSQL, I get this error: `"Contact failed to create: Required fields are missing: [LastName]"` but the LastName field is positively not empty or null. Today is the first time receiving this error on the Contact – I've successfully created Contact records this way in the past. To start, I've checked on this with the vendor and was told it has something to do with permissions of the user account under which the replication is running. I've checked everything I can think of related to the running user's permissions on the Contact record, but before throwing it back at the vendor I want to make sure there isn't anything obvious I'm missing.

Here is what I've checked so far:

- Role: Admin
- Profile: System Administrator
- Profile has all object permissions enabled
- Read and Edit permissions on the Name field are both set
- Field-level security on the Name field is set to visible (read-only not selected)
- No Contact triggers changing the value of LastName
- No validation rules set on the LastName field
- No workflow rules set on the LastName field
- Confirmed I can create the identical record through the GUI under the running user

Is there anything else I should check? Is it fair to think it could be related to vendor replication code?

Comment: Some Validation Rules / Sharing Settings?

Comment: Check `FirstName`, `LastName` permissions, `Name` on Contact is a readonly field. Have you added any workflows or triggers recently that might be "sanitizing" the names, looking for duplicates and whatnot? Might be something in your code that eventually wipes the value. What happens if you take "this user" and attempt to create Contact with same data from GUI?

Comment: Many a times it is easy to get the data and try to recreate the sample data in the system manually.You can easily identify if the error is a validation error. It could be highly possible that there are some validation rules that are triggered and the system is throwing the top error from stack. Just try to insert the data you are trying to create from the API.It is a personal approach that I would take even thought it is a little cumbersome and painful approach for many

Comment: Thanks for everyone's response – I am able to confirm that the record was created through the GUI and that there aren't any triggers, validation rules, or workflows acting on the field. I've updated the question to reflect these findings.

Comment: just curious are you creating the sample record in the GUI from the same account as the integration account  and when you create the contact can you open up your developer console and try to see 1) If there is an exception keyword 2) the same error message pasted in the question. It is highly possible some people use try catch in the background code to prevent errors from showing up on the screen.One final check also is to see if the source is providing the Lastname for the target: (salesforce) contact

Comment: @rao Yup, same account being used in the integration created the record in the GUI, and there isn't any code that's suppressing the error. I'm going to push the vendor again for more support on the issue.

Comment: To pinpoint it to the integration tool, maybe you can try creating a csv with the data for the contact and try creating it using Dataloader or Jitterbit. If it is successful there, then you know you can create contacts through the API.

Comment: Did you check for any code that might be firing and creating a second new contact record that might have a blank last name?

Comment: Can you share the contact fields you are trying to insert and how are they mapped? as well as the mapping structures, I had a hard time the first time setting up this objects to be replicated from one table to another, sometimes the error was that when you map certain fields it may change your record type and that automatically would change the required fields, or maybe you are mapping a Name instead of FirstName field Regards!

Comment: Your using MSSQL to upload the data to salesforce.  Is it possible that the account associated with the MSSQL server is attempting the update and that is what is being passed?

Comment: Also, is this happening for all records or just an occasion issue?  Could it have to do with particular records being locked out? (IE: Account Record not allowing the changes)

My only other thought is that if this is happening on certain accounts but not others it is related to the sales force account being updated and not necessarily the SQL server account.

Comment: Just let me know  which wsdl you are using to connect Enterprise or partner.

Comment: One possibility is that there is a before trigger firing that tries to set the name from elsewhere and erroneously empties the field.

Answer (score 3):

In short, there's four components that determine what goes into Salesforce (assuming stable connections, no weird firewalls that strip data from messages etc).

1. The original data
2. The mapping of original data to SF Objects
3. Triggers etc. in SF
4. Access rights in SF

It seems you ruled out 1, 3 and 4 to be the problem, so there's no other conclusion that 2 is the problem.

Check a network analyzer like WireShark to see what is actually going over the line, and try other import tools like DataLoader to check if the import still fails when you know that 2 is good. Possibly, create an Apex Trigger on the Account Object and `System.debug(...)` all incoming data, especially the LastName field.

Answer (score 0):

Is it definitely a contact record that is causing this error? Have you got person accounts enabled on your org? These are like a hybrid of account and contact.

I've seen an error message like this during insert of an account, when the record type of the account was for a person account but the contact mandatory fields were missing.